# when i create a new .net core mvc project the Startup.cs file doesnt create in project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i create new .net core mvc project in vs 2022 .net6 it hasn't Startup.cs file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqDfA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After .NET Core 6.0,

Program.cs includes Startup.cs as well.

You can do everything in Program.cs that you can do at Startup.cs

I guess they made this to simplify the code.